# Index not being used for django desc

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a django model with the following indexes:

```
class Meta:
    indexes = [
        models.Index(fields=['-current']),
        models.Index(fields=['current']),
    ]
```

The relevant field is defined as:

```
current = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

These were added and I ran the migration and saw the results:

```
  companies/migrations/0294_auto_20220110_1155.py
    - Create index companies_c_current_f2c815_idx on field(s) -current of model company
    - Create index companies_c_current_c8bcb7_idx on field(s) current of model company
```

I've found that running a django-rest-framework query with ordering=current is ~5x faster than with ordering=-current. Using PSQL explain I get the following:

```
# explain analyze select * from company order by current desc nulls last limit 100;
                                            

    QUERY PLAN                                                                       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=41028.75..41040.42 rows=100 width=1223) (actual time=866.587..867.650 rows=100 loops=1)   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=41028.75..68747.19 rows=237570 width=1223) (actual time=866.585..867.644 rows=100 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         ->  Sort  (cost=40028.73..40325.69 rows=118785 width=1223) (actual time=849.292..849.296 rows=48 loops=3)
               Sort Key: current DESC NULLS LAST
               Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 275kB
               Worker 0:  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 314kB
               Worker 1:  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 299kB
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on companies_company  (cost=0.00..35488.85 rows=118785 width=1223) (actual time=0.278..756.498 rows=95028 loops=3)
 Planning Time: 0.444 ms
 Execution Time: 867.759 ms
(12 rows)


# explain analyze select * from company order by current asc nulls last limit 100;
                                                         

    QUERY PLAN                                                                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.42..49.79 rows=100 width=1223) (actual time=1.700..13.268 rows=100 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan Backward using companies_c_current_f2c815_idx on companies_company  (cost=0.42..140727.06 rows=285084 width=1223) (actual time=1.698..13.244 rows=100 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 1.139 ms
 Execution Time: 13.426 ms
(4 rows)
```

It seems clear from the above that the asc is using the index while the desc is not, which explains the time difference. My question is: why not? Is there a different way the index needs to be added to make sure it's used for both asc and desc? I originally tried adding it to the model field definition with `db_index=True` but that yielded the same issue.

Comment: Please post the results of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on each query not just simple explain.

Comment: @Belayer updated with results of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`

Comment: "desc nulls last" vs "asc nulls last", that's the difference between not using the current index and using this index. You don't have an index that supports the first sort. If you would try "desc nulls first" the database could use the index. Otherwise you have to create an index that has the sort order you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index can be scanned in both directions, but it needs to be sorted exactly like the `ORDER BY` clause it is intended by default. A plain index is sorted in `ASC NULLS LAST` order, so it can support that order or the reverse, namely `DESC NULLS FIRST`. To create an index that can support your `ORDER BY` clause, use

```
CREATE INDEX ON companies_company (current ASC NULLS FIRST);
```

Comment: is there a way to add this in django / python model definition, or only via direct SQL migration?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about Django.